# Write Pandas Dataframe parquet metadata with partition columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, metadata, pyarrow

I am able to write a parquet file with partition_cols, but not the respective metadata. Seems there's a schema mismatch on the table vs metadata due to the columns in my partition.

Need some help sorting out what I'm doing wrong -

The code,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dictReprForDf)

table=pa.Table.from_pandas(df)

metadata_collector=[]

pq.write_to_dataset(table, outputFilePath, metadata_collector=metadata_collector, partition_cols=['A','B','C'])

pq.write_metadata(table.schema, outputFilePath+'/_common_metadata')

pq.write_metadata(table.schema, outputFilePath+'/_metadata',metadata_collector=metadata_collector)
```

Error:

```
File "pyarrow\_parquet.pyx", line 616, in pyarrow._parquet.FileMetaData.append_row_groups
RuntimeError: AppendRowGroups require equal schema
```

Noteworthy that this code works/no errors if I don't set partition_cols on the pq.write_to_dataset.

Comment: I noticed this myself last week.  I've just opened [ARROW-13269](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-13269) to track the fix.  As a workaround you can remove the partition columns from table.schema.  Although your resulting `_metadata` and `_common_metadata` will not contain all of the fields.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution by checking [how they do this in `dask`](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/21b99af0e12a6682d93bbbc234d28b8ab74c6074/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/arrow.py#L105).

```
root_path = Path("partitioned_data")
metadata_collector = []
partition_cols = ["partition_col1", "partition_col2"]

subschema = table.schema

for col in partition_cols:
    subschema = subschema.remove(subschema.get_field_index(col))

pa.parquet.write_to_dataset(
    table, root_path=root_path, partition_cols=partition_cols,
    metadata_collector=metadata_collector,
)

pq.write_metadata(subschema, root_path / "_common_metadata")
pq.write_metadata(subschema, root_path / "_metadata", metadata_collector=metadata_collector)
```